# log4j not working in grails

Tags: grails, log4j

I have the following configuration for log4j

```
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    }

    info 'grails.app.controllers'

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

when I do log.info in my controller, I don't see any output being logged in to the console. Any reasons why ?

Comment: What version of Grails?  `grails.app.controllers` is correct for Grails 2.x but it needs to be `grails.app.controller` (no "s") for 1.3.x and earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Just had  to add grails.app and that did the trick